# Differential Equations, can't find out what kind of question it is.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

$$2xy(1+y^2)dx - (1+x^2+x^2y^2)dy = 0$$

I haven't had my first test yet, so it's most likely that this equation is separable, homogeneous, exact, linear or Bernoulli. It would definitely be exact if there wasn't a 1+ on the dy side. But maybe there's something I am not seeing yet?

Comment: After trying all the methods for those that you mention, you'll have your answer.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas clearly it's not.

Comment: Oh right, the "1+". Sorry, I'm removing the previous comment.

Comment: @JohnB I had 10 questions, i was able to figure them out all except this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2x+6xy^2$$
$$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2x-2xy^2$$
then the equation is **not** exact. For integral factor we see
$$p(y)=\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{-M}=-2\dfrac{1+2y^2}{y(1+y^2)}$$
We have integral factor
$$I=e^{\int p(y)dy}=\dfrac{1}{y^2(1+y^2)}$$
then the equation
$$\dfrac{2x}{y}dx-\dfrac{1+x^2+x^2y^2}{y^2(1+y^2)}dy=0$$
is exact.

Answer (score 0):

This equation becomes "nicer" if we start using $x=\sqrt z$ which makes
$$2xy(1+y^2)\frac{dx}{dy} - (1+x^2+x^2y^2) = 0$$
$$y(1+y^2)\frac{dz}{dy}-(1+y^2)z-1=0$$ So, the homogeneous part is simple
$$y(1+y^2)\frac{dz}{dy}-(1+y^2)z=0\implies y\frac{dz}{dy}-z=0\implies z=y+C$$ and, using the method of variation of parameters leads to $$C=-1-y\tan^{-1}(y)+K$$ making finally $$x=\pm \sqrt{Ky-1-y\tan^{-1}(y)}$$